# Permission set update error

Tags: security, permissions, user-management

My application is Managed package. I have edited permisiion set , while am updating the following error message is displaying..

Permission Download AppExchange Packages depends on permission(s): Create and Manage Communities
Permission Manage Auth. Providers depends on permission(s): Create and Manage Communities
Permission Author Apex depends on permission(s): Create and Manage Communities
Permission Modify All Data depends on permission(s): Create and Manage Communities

what is wrong with me?

From where can i set 'Create and Manage Communities' permission?

Answer (score 3):

You can set "Create and Manage Communities" under System Permissions, or just search for the permission if you have the Enhanced Profile View.  That message seems to be a new thing for the Summer '13 release.

Answer (score 1):

From a packaging standpoint, we don't ever package user permissions. Since both Modify All Data and Create and Manage Communities permissions are user permissions, this dependency error should have nothing to do with being a managed package. However, you do need to resolve the dependency issue to save the profile or permission set.

Use the find settings box in the toolbar of the permission set to search for 'Create and Manage Communities' - if nothing comes up, you have a different issue since the dependent permissions (Modify All Data, Author Apex, and Download AppExchange Packages) shouldn't be showing up either.